# Checking one sub query to contain results of the other in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, window-functions

I am trying to write a query that should perform `join` (or `where` clause) using the following criteria:

> Subquery of left table should contain results of subquery from the right table (results also should be grouped).

[image: Tables (diagram)]

[sql script creating tables with data](https://ufile.io/4c5at)

Exact criteria is the following:

Select clients who:

> For each Question.Id in [ClientSegment]'s questionIds
>
> Should be at least one (equivalent on Any in LINQ) ClientAnswers.AnswerId from those in [ClientSegmentAnswers]

How I can achieve that without using for loops (cursors) in a single query?

**UPD**

Added script for creating tables and data

**Expected result**

Query that selects Bob as only matching consumers for ClientSegment with id = 1;

Answer (score 0):

SQL JOINS will help for achieve this in single query,

E.g :

```
select 
c.name,
c.id,
...
from Question as que 
left join ClientSegment as cs on que.id=cs.id
left join ClientSegmentAnswers as csans on  csans.ClientSegmentID=cs.id
left join Answer as ans on ans.id=csans.answerid
left join ClientAnswer as ca on ca.answerid=ans.answerid
left join Client as c on c.id=ca.ClientID
where ca.ClientID is not null
```

This query will return only clientname who are answering  atleast one question also you can modify the query for your need.

Comment: I've edit question, added sample data. the query you suggested doesnt return what's expected, unfortunately

Comment: You mean, Want to select only segment type 1 clients? It is difficult to achieve using your structure because some of the answer id come for both segment types E.g: AnswerID - 4. But you can able to omit Type "2" using left join query.

Comment: No, answer has foreign key, so answer belongs to only one question